# karaf / filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.logging.log4j)(version>=2.17.0)

Tags: java, log4j2, apache-karaf

I am upgrading from log4j-slf4j-impl 2.12.0  to 2.17.1. In my previous code I have nothing else except

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now that I have upgraded to 2.17.1 I got the following error:

org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl/2.17.1: missing requirement [org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl/2.17.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.logging.log4j)(version>=2.17.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"
at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:420)
at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378)
at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:393)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1062)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

so I have included in my pom.xml two more dependencies to check if that allivates the problem. These other two dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

but it does not help. Compilation process is just fine. Running is where the problem exist.

this is part of my pom.xml:

```
    <slf4j.version>2.17.1</slf4j.version>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/Activator.java</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- test scoped dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logger dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**what else I am missing here ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to fix the logshell security issue the easiest way is to install latest version of Apache karaf `4.3.x` or `4.2.X` as versions 4.3.5 and 4.2.14 should fix the issue.

Your exception is caused by the fact that none of the installed bundles export following package `org.apache.logging.log4j` within version range of 2.17.0 - 3.0.0.

If you're new to OSGi then its good to understand that **bundles don't contain any of their dependencies by default** instead the bundle contains import-package information that tells the OSGi runtime to provide latest packages that the bundle depends on that fall within the specified version range.

This means that in order to start the bundle you'll have to install bundles that satisfy its dependencies by exporting whatever packages or osgi services the bundle depends upon.

To see if specific package is being exported by a bundle you can use command:

```sh
package:exports -p <package>
package:exports -p org.apache.logging.log4j
```

This prints details about which bundles export which version of the specified package which should help troubleshoot osgi.wiring.package errors.

To see packages exported by installed bundle you can use:

```sh
package:exports -b <bundle ID>
```

Apache Karaf uses [pax-logging](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging) to provide logging support for bundles. So you might look in to installing more recent version of pax-logging-api that exports [log4j](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/logging-2.0.14/pax-logging-api/osgi.bnd#L65-L107) packages for bundles to use.

---

Apache karaf installs some version of pax-logging-api and pax-logging-log4j2 on first startup. If you want karaf to install more recent version of these bundles instead you can do so by adding more recent versions of following bundles (jars):

- pax-logging-api
- pax-logging-log4j2
- pax-logging-logback

to `karaf/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/<artifact-name>/<version>/` then modify `startup.properties` to install those versions instead. Do note that there are two versions of pax-logging available 1.x.x and 2.x.x so check which version karaf uses to see whether to use latest 1.x.x or 2.x.x of pax-logging.

Its also possible to blacklist bundles in `org.apache.karaf.features.xml` to prevent them from getting installed.

```xml
<!-- blacklist versions 1.0 - 1.11.11 -->
<blacklistedBundles>
   <bundle>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/[1,1.11.12)</bundle>
   <bundle>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/[1,1.11.12)</bundle>
   <bundle>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-logback/[1,1.11.12)</bundle>
</blacklistedBundles>
```

Remove data folder to reset karaf to clean state, start karaf and it should have more recent version of pax-logging installed.