# Pax logging issue with karaf 4.2.6

Tags: logging, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, pax

I am updating karaf 2 to karaf 4. Seeing below error with karaf 4

```
   2/10/22
    10:14:50.724 AM 
    2022-02-10 04:44:50,724 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel                  | Felix                            |  | Bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [90] Error stopping bundle. (java.lang.NullPointerException) java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.getLogLevel(PaxLoggerImpl.java:267)[6:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.8.2]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.getLogLevel(TrackingLogger.java:136)
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.getLevel(Log4jv2Logger.java:156)
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.isEnabled(Log4jv2Logger.java:63)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1959)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1297)
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator.stop(Activator.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.stopActivator(SecureAction.java:719)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.12.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.stopBundle(Felix.java:2636)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.12.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1391)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.12.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.12.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_172]
```

Comment: How do you _update_? Stack trace shows pax-logging 1.8.2, and Karaf 4.2.x uses pax-logging 1.11.x.

Comment: `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-logging-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
`

**@GrzegorzGrzybek I have added above mentioned dependency in pom.xml file**

Comment: `<feature name="log4j1">
    <bundle>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.2</bundle>
</feature>
`
@GrzegorzGrzybek feature.xml file

Comment: you don't have to install a `log4j1` feature. Karaf has built in support for pax-logging in proper version.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Thanks...I will try that.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek 
`org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.2/pax-logging-api-1.8.2.jar=8
org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.2/pax-logging-service-1.8.2.jar=8`
startup.properties 
i have remove it from here as well...do I need to keep it with updated version of pax-logging 1.11.x.

Comment: Did you start with clean Karaf 4? You should not randomly add bundles to startup.properties. Better try "custom Karaf distro" - https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_custom_distributions

Comment: INFO: Installing and starting initial bundles
Feb 14, 2022 6:40:55 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch
INFO: All initial bundles installed and set to start
Feb 14, 2022 6:40:55 AM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: Trying to lock /usr/local/container/lock
INFO: Lock acquired
Feb 14, 2022 6:40:55 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback 
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
@GrzegorzGrzybek Getting above error after removing log4j1 feature...although now I am not seeing error ***Error stopping bundle. (java.lang.NullPointerException)*** .

Comment: Please start with fresh Karaf downloaded from https://karaf.apache.org/download.html

Comment: I am using custom karaf distribution.
<groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId> <artifactId>framework</artifactId> <version>${karaf4.version}</version> <type>kar</type> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId> <artifactId>standard</artifactId> <version>${karaf4.version}</version> <classifier>features</classifier> <type>xml</type> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> @GrzegorzGrzybek

Comment: custom Karaf distro allows you to do lots of changes to features/startup bundles. I'd have to see your entire configuration.

Comment: Wrote about manually updating pax-logging in karaf in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70544503/16480631) maybe it helps.